# Runnable in service working in a main thread

Tags: java, android, runnable

I'm new in android programming.
Trying to get some useful data set from web json(network task) and parse it.
So i choose for this `Service`, for making background job. How do i properly install repeated task with `Handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval)` not in the `main` thread?

Help me please to figure this out?

Comment: You aren't allowed to perform networking operations on the main thread. Try using a separate thread.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This code looks like you are trying to do something in the background every five seconds. Is that correct? If so, when is this work starting up, and when will this work ever stop?

Comment: I try to get some json data from webpage and parse it. Yes, 5 sec is enough to parse json web page. At least it's enough in androidVM.

Answer (score 1):

`IntentService` intents run on a background worker thread.

However, you seem to be posting a runnable doing network operations to a handler which is likely on the UI thread since you're getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

This explains the problem. Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish so we can suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The exception name `NetworkOnMainThreadException` says it all. You should not do networking in the main thread. There are a lot of solutions for this problem using `AsyncTask` is one of them.

Here is an example from [AndroidDevelopers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Another option is to use a `Service`. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) you can find a good tutorial on services.

Comment: An `AsyncTask` is rarely the right answer in a service, as the point behind an `AsyncTask` is to allow some work to be done on the main application thread, which is almost never needed in a service.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But a thought that IntentService is running in a different thread and i can deal without AsynTask.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main behaviors of Android programming is that the UI thread (i.e., the one that interacts with the user) has to be as free as it can. This means that if you declared a Network Connection within the UI thread, you will collapse it and the user will get a nice ANR (Android Not Responding).

For tasks that involves network connections, I'd recommend one of these:

- If your network task is limited in time and it ends within a short time after starting, I'd recommend using an `AsyncTask`.
- If you need an undefined-in-time network connection, or a forever-loop socket and so, use a `Service`, they're intended exactly for this.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Also this is only thrown for applications targeting the `Honeycomb` SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

So use a separate thread for network operations.

For more details visit [developer android site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).